# WebGL and UNet. Cant seem to get in proper contact with server from a browser

Tags: unity-game-engine, websocket, unity-webgl, unity3d-unet

I am trying to setup a multiplayer game to be played through a browser using UNet. In the editor everything works fine, I followed a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGkkaNkq8co) that said it should work in webgl but sadly it does not. There are two scripts as of yet one for the client and one for the server linked below. This is using mostly the LLAPI.

Whether I use the networkServer.usewebsocket = true or not, the result is the same.

The debug of "finished connection" does show so it completes the OnConnection function.

From the editor everything works fine but from the browser I get the following error:

"Attempt to send to not connected connection {1}" -- Since I get this error when ASKNAME is asked and when ASKPOSITION is asked I suspect that the SEND function is the problem im trying to send something the browser cant understand. But I don't know why.

```
private int port = 3001;
private List<ServerClient> clients = new List<ServerClient>();
private float lastMovementUpdate;
private float movementUpdateRate = 0.05f;
private int socketId;
private int webHostId;
private int reliableChannel;
private int unReliableChannel;
private bool isStarted = false;
private byte error;

private void Start()
{
 NetworkTransport.Init();
 ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();
 reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
 unReliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
 HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);
 socketId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null);
 webHostId = NetworkTransport.AddWebsocketHost(topo, port, null);
 isStarted = true;
 }

  private void Update()
 {
 if (!isStarted)
     return;
 int recHostId;
 int connectionId;
 int channelId;
 byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
 int bufferSize = 1024;
 int dataSize;
 byte error;
 NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);
 switch (recData)
 {
     case NetworkEventType.Nothing:         //1
         break;
     case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:    //2
         Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + "has connected");
         OnConnection(connectionId);
         break;
     case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:       //3
         string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(recBuffer, 0, dataSize);
         Debug.Log("Receiving From " + connectionId + "has sent : " + msg);
         string[] splitData = msg.Split('|');
         switch (splitData[0])
         {
             case "NAMEIS":
                 OnNameIS(connectionId, splitData[1]);
                 break;
             case "MYPOSITION":
                 OnMyPosition(connectionId, float.Parse(splitData[1]), float.Parse(splitData[2]));
                 break;
             default:
                 Debug.Log("invalid message : " + msg);
                 break;
         }

         break;

     case NetworkEventType.DisconnectEvent: //4
         Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + "has disconnected");
         OnDiconnection(connectionId);
         break;
 }
 if (clients.Count > 0)
 {
     if (Time.time - lastMovementUpdate > movementUpdateRate)
     {
         lastMovementUpdate = Time.time;
         string posMsg = "ASKPOSITION|";
         foreach (ServerClient sc in clients)
             posMsg += sc.connectionId.ToString() + '%' + sc.position.x.ToString() + '%' + sc.position.y.ToString() + '|';
         posMsg = posMsg.Trim('|');
         Send(posMsg, unReliableChannel, clients);
     }
 }
 }

 private void OnConnection(int cnnId)
 {
 Debug.Log("Arrived at connection");
 ServerClient c = new ServerClient();
 c.connectionId = cnnId;
 c.playerName = "TEMP";
 clients.Add(c);
 string msg = "ASKNAME|" + cnnId + "|";
 foreach (ServerClient sc in clients)
     msg += sc.playerName + '%' + sc.connectionId + '|';
     msg = msg.Trim('|');
 Send(msg, reliableChannel, cnnId);
 Debug.Log("Finished at connection");
 }

 private void OnNameIS(int cnnId, string playerName)
 {
 // link the name to the connection ID
 clients.Find(x => x.connectionId == cnnId).playerName = playerName;
 // Tell evertone that a new player has connected
 Send("CNN|" + playerName + '|' + cnnId, reliableChannel, clients);
 }

 private void Send(string message, int channelId, int cnnId)
 {
 List<ServerClient> c = new List<ServerClient>();
 c.Add(clients.Find(x => x.connectionId == cnnId));
 Send(message, channelId, c);
 }

 private void Send(string message, int channelId, List<ServerClient> c)
 {
 Debug.Log("sending : " + message);
 byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
 foreach(ServerClient sc in c)
 {
     NetworkTransport.Send(socketId, sc.connectionId, channelId, msg, message.Length * sizeof(char), out error);
 }
 }

 private void OnDiconnection(int cnnId)
 {
 clients.Remove(clients.Find(x => x.connectionId == cnnId));
 string msg = "DC|" + cnnId;
 Send(msg, reliableChannel, clients);
 }

 private void OnMyPosition(int cnnId, float x, float y)
 {
 clients.Find(clientInQuestion => clientInQuestion.connectionId == cnnId).position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
 }
```

**And then the client:**

```
     private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 100;

 private int port = 3001;

 private int hostId;
 private int webHostId;
 private int reliableChannel;
 private int unReliableChannel;

 private int connectionId;
 private int clientId;


 private bool isConnected = false;

 public bool isStarted = false;

 private float connectionTime;

 private string playerName;

 private byte error;

 public GameObject playerPrefab;
 public Dictionary<int, player> players = new Dictionary<int, player>();

 public void Connect()
 {
     Debug.Log("connecting...");
     // does player have a name?
     string pName = GameObject.Find("NameInput").GetComponent<InputField>().text;
     if (pName == "")
     {
         Debug.Log("Enter a name");
         return;
     }

     playerName = pName;



     NetworkTransport.Init();
     ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

     reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
     unReliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);

     HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

     hostId = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, 0);

     connectionId = NetworkTransport.Connect(hostId, "127.0.0.1", port, 0, out error);

     connectionTime = Time.time;

     isConnected = true;

     Debug.Log("connected");
 }

 private void Update()
 {
     connectionTime += Time.deltaTime;

     if (!isConnected)

         return;

     int recHostId;
     int connectionId;
     int channelId;
     byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
     int bufferSize = 1024;
     int dataSize;
     byte error;
     NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);
     switch (recData)
     {
         case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:
             string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(recBuffer, 0, dataSize);
             Debug.Log("receiving : " + msg);
             string[] splitData = msg.Split('|');


             switch (splitData[0])
             {
                 case "ASKNAME":
                     OnAskName(splitData);
                     break;
                 case "CNN":
                     SpawnPlayer(splitData[1], int.Parse(splitData[2]));
                     break;
                 case "DC":
                     playerDisconnected(int.Parse(splitData[1]));
                     break;
                 case "ASKPOSITION":
                     OnAskPosition(splitData);
                     break;

                 default:
                     Debug.Log("invalid message : " + msg);
                     break;
             }

             break;

     }
 }

 private void OnAskName(string[] data)
 {
     // set the client ID
     clientId = int.Parse(data[1]);

     // send our name to the server
     Send("NAMEIS|" + playerName, reliableChannel);

     // create all the other players
     for (int i = 2; i < data.Length - 1; i++)
     {
         string[] d = data[i].Split('%');
         SpawnPlayer(d[0], int.Parse(d[1]));
     }
 }

 private void OnAskPosition(string[] data)
 {

     if (!isStarted)
         return;

     //update everyone else
     for (int i = 1; i <= data.Length-1; i++)
     {
         string[] d = data[i].Split('%');

         //prevent the server from updating us
         if (clientId != int.Parse(d[0]))
         {
             Debug.Log("updating position");
             Vector3 position = Vector3.zero;
             position.x = float.Parse(d[1]);
             position.y = float.Parse(d[2]);
             players[int.Parse(d[0])].avatar.transform.position = position;
         }
     }

     //send out own position
     Vector3 myPosition = players[clientId].avatar.transform.position;
     string m = "MYPOSITION|" + myPosition.x.ToString() + '|' + myPosition.y.ToString();
     Send(m, unReliableChannel);

 }

 private void SpawnPlayer(string playerName, int cnnId)
 {
     GameObject go = Instantiate(playerPrefab) as GameObject;

     // is this ours?

     if(cnnId == clientId)
     {
         // add mobility
         go.AddComponent<PlayerController>();

         // remove Canvas
         GameObject.Find("Canvas").SetActive(false);

         isStarted = true;
     }

     player p = new player();
     p.avatar = go;
     p.playerName = playerName;
     p.avatar.GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>().text = playerName;
     p.connectionId = cnnId;

     players.Add(cnnId, p);
 }

 private void Send(string message, int channelId)
 {
     Debug.Log("sending : " + message);
     byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
     NetworkTransport.Send(hostId, connectionId, channelId, msg, message.Length * sizeof(char), out error);
 }

 private void playerDisconnected(int cnnId)
 {
     Destroy(players[cnnId].avatar);
     Debug.Log("player : " + players[cnnId].playerName + " has disconnected");
     players.Remove(cnnId);
 }
}
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated, I have tried looking through the documentation but I feel I have done everything that it says to do in that (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingTransport.html) at the bottom it talks about webgl support, but it doesn't seem to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue,

Answer was that I was sending to HostID and not webSocketId

so this:

```
    private void Send(string message, int channelId, List<ServerClient> c)
{
    Debug.Log("sending : " + message);
    byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
    foreach(ServerClient sc in c)
    {
        NetworkTransport.Send(hostId, sc.connectionId, channelId, msg, message.Length * sizeof(char), out error);
    }
}
```

was changed to this:

```
    private void Send(string message, int channelId, List<ServerClient> c)
{
    Debug.Log("sending : " + message);
    byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
    foreach(ServerClient sc in c)
    {
        NetworkTransport.Send(webSocketId, sc.connectionId, channelId, msg, message.Length * sizeof(char), out error);
    }
}
```